# How to calculate simplified model of speaker impedance given a few data points

Tags: oscillator, impedance, speakers

I'm given a couple of data points of the impedance of a simplified speaker model (Series R with parallel R, L, C):

- Re ... DC resistance (the series R)
- Fs ... resonance frequency (in Hz)
- Rm ... impedance at resonance (in Ω)
- impedance at the two frequencies above and below Fs where impedance equals Re*sqrt(Rm/Re)

Given this, how do I calculate the impedance at any frequency?

Comment: The main resonance of a speaker is mechanical, not electrical.

Comment: From its Thiele-Small parameters. Here is a link where to start: http://www.integracoustics.com/MUG/MUG/articles/woofer/

Comment: For a full list of parameters  https://mynewmicrophone.com/full-list-thiele-small-speaker-parameters-w-descriptions/#Lces:-Electrical-Inductance-Including-Air-Load